# Running Multiple instances of Java app via bash, how to access their shell menu?

Tags: java, linux, bash, command-line, jar

So I got the job of testing the new java engine. 
The programmer who created it made me a test jar file so I can test some crashmoments and loadbalancing.

*I know it's a load of text here, but I hope someone can give me a great answer! Thanks in advance for reading!*

I wanted to automate the testing process so I created a bash file.

So far what it does is loop for a couple of times, in which it starts the jar file:

```
java -jar /mnt/nas/i/testsail/clusteng.jar 2>> /dev/null &
```

After that it gets the processId of the just started java app:

```
process_ids[$i]=$!
```

So eventually I have like 5 instances of that jar, all with their related processId.

Now my problem is, the programmer added a little shell around the app, in which I can tell it at what moment to crash. If I just start the engine from the commandline, it shows me that shell and I can just type 'fail moment_Of_Faillure' and it will ungracefully fail there.

Ofcourse now I want to give each instance another failmoment, and I want to randomize that from the bash script.

My question is; **How can I give commands to each instance from within the bash script?**

I will post the complete bash script here:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Engine testing script; Starts multiple engine instances and shoots one every 20 seconds
clear
echo "#####################"
echo "# Start $1 processes #"
echo "#####################"
echo ""

# create number of processes
for ((  i = 1 ;  i <= $1;  i++  ))
do
    if test $i == 1
    then
        echo "Starting process: $i -> Master Process"
    else
        echo "Starting process: $i"
    fi

    #$! = last started process
    java -jar /mnt/nas/i/testsail/clusteng.jar 2>> /dev/null &
    process_ids[$i]=$!
    echo "PID $!"
    echo ""

    sleep 20
done

sleep 20

for ((  i = 1 ;  i <= $1;  i++  ))
do
    echo "Kill PID:${process_ids[$i]}"
    #ech `FAIL BEFORE_RANK_DISTRIBUTION` > fifo$i
    kill -9 ${process_ids[$i]}
    echo ""
    if test $i != $1
    then
       sleep 20
    fi
done

# run errorcheck
. `./checklogs`
```

Comment: your description of the shell script and the actual shell script seem to differ a bit.  you talk about commands which affect the instances, but the script you posted just kills an instance ever 20 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect application of [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)